# SAS to Informatica migration

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, information-extraction

I am stuck at one point. We have 700 SAS scripts in which we have some ETL logic is written,  we have to migrate it into Informatica. I understood the logic and its quite easy to implement it but my client is saying that don't do it manually, find out some way so that we can automate it. By automation he means that implement some way by which ETL code will be read automatically and then mapping will also be designed automatically. Now my question is, Is that possible? Can we achieve this if yes then please share some insight if not then is there any other alternate way?

Comment: Sounds like two distinct problems: write a generic SAS to Informatica converter OR get you existing project ported to Informatica. Two different problems. But maybe there are actually 7000 SAS scripts but only 700 priority, then it might make sense to invest in a generic converter. But in either situation you would have to figure out how to do it by hand in order to create a generic method. He might have given you a chicken/egg problem.

Comment: Thanks #HolaSenor.... So you mean to say that I have to it manually :(